# Determing code rate

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Let $C \in \{ 0,1\}^7 $ be a code with the following code words :

0000000, 1110000, 0001111, 1001001, 0110110, 1000110, 0111001, 0010101,
1101010, 0011010, 1100101, 0100011, 1011100, 0101100, 1010011, 1111111.

Determine the code rate of this code.

So the formula is $R = \frac{log_q |C|}{n}$ where $q$ is the number of Symbols in the alphabet and $n$ is the block length.

In this particular case my assumption is that $q=128$ and $n=7$ and $|C|=16$.
With this assumption I get that the Code rate is $R=\frac{4}{49}$. I am doubtful because this seems to be a pretty bad code rate. Can anyone please confirm that this is the correct code rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code rate is $4/7$. Just forget about the formulas and understand the essence of coding. So the question is how many information bits do you have and how many coding bits? Code bits $=7$ this is what we already know. You are given $16$ code words and from this you need to find how many information bits you have. How many? and why?

Comment: Do you mean 16 code words? The minimum distance between the code words is 3. So that means the number of information bits is 4. Am I correct?

Comment: yes code words, miswritten. code rate has very little to do with minimum distance. Simply you have information bits and you wanna add redundancy into your information bits and you will obtain code bits. Code rate will give you the information how much redundancy you added. If too much redundancy then very little code rate if very good code rate then very little redundancy and very little protection against errors! so yes $16$ code words and how many bits? for example with $3$ bits you can obtain only $2^3$ different variations right? does that say something to you?

Comment: 7 bits. That means my code rate is $16/2^7$?

Comment: Ok it seems it wont work in this way. You have $4$ information bits and $\log_2 16=4$. If you have $4$ information bits then you can create $16$ code words, $2^4=16$.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I am still a little confused. How could you determine that there are 4 information bits. I mean why did you use $\log_2 16$? Is the base 2 because we have {$0,1$} ?

Comment: yes because we have zeros and ones and this says $q=2$. Write it down and you will immediately see: $\{0000,0001,....\}$ there are altogether $16$ and there is a BIJECTIVE mapping from the information words to code words. this part is very important. did you get it now?

Comment: The formula is clear to me now, q is the number of symbols in the alphabet and not the number of words that can be build with that alphabet. That was my confusion from the begin. Thank you very much !